# a concise way to import many modules with common namespace prefixes

Tags: python, syntax, namespaces, python-import, idioms

I often find myself importing classes from modules that only differ in the last part of their namespace, e.g:

```
from a.b.c.d import Class1
from a.b.c.e import Class2
from a.b.c.f import Class3
```

Is there some way for me to type the common `a.b.c.` part just once?

I know that if they all had exactly the same namespace, i.e.

```
from a.b.c import Class1
from a.b.c import Class2
from a.b.c import Class3
```

Then I could just type

```
from a.b.c import (Class1, Class2, Class3)
```

So for my first example, I tried things like

```
from a.b.c import (d.Class1 as Class1, 
                   e.Class2 as Class2, 
                   f.Class3 as Class3)
```

... but that didn't work.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is one of your own packages (or if you willing and abale to maintain a fork...) you can use the `a.b.c` package as a facade:

```
# a/b/c/__init__.py
from d import Class1
from e import Class2
from f import Class3
```

Then:

```
# client code:
from a.b.c import Class1, Class2, Class3
```

will work.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no syntax to import nested items as local names like that.

You could import the different modules, then assign to local names:

```
from a.b.c import d, e, f
Class1, Class2, Class3 = d.Class1, e.Class2, f.Class3
del d, e, f
```

but that's no more readable or concise.